# Why my Gvim often stop working on Win7?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

My Gvim often stop working on Windows7:
[image]

I download a prebuilt gvim version, I forgot the link page.
I use Vundle as my vim plugin manager:
[image]

Please help me...
Sometimes I type a little fast, I cannot realize what I have type.
Maybe I press some error key which caused the gvim stop.
But I don't know what key will cause the gvim stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Vim version 7.4.280 is a *development snapshot*; it is not a stabilized version. Either move back to [this MR version](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/pc/gvim74.exe) (and hope that the problem isn't there), or regularly update to the latest available build. Ideally, you'll then debug into / collect stacktraces in case of crashes, and report this problem, so that the devs can do something about it.

Comment: Because I need vim with lua and python2.7 support, so I download a prebuild version.

Comment: Do you have some recommandation about vim with lua/python/perl support version?

Comment: actually it's 7.4.648, but thanks, I will install another stable version of gvim.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  @Ingo Karkat recommandation.

I download another prebuild gvim for windows version.

I find a very good all-in-one gvim for windows on Bitbucket:

https://bitbucket.org/Alexander-Shukaev/vim-for-windows/downloads

This gvim support lua/python2.7.x/python3.4.x/ruby/perl, and it include all the lua52.dll/python27.dll/python34.dll/... files. So vimers do NOT have to download the matchde version script dll files.

I think this will meet most of vimer's need.